# Worksheet Change Script doesn't seem to be running properly - Not sure why

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a table I'm tracking progress of various projects in and I want to change the percentage complete (in col G) when the status (in row A) changes. I wrote the script in the middle to change the cell based on the other but the outside piece (meant to make the script run when a cell in Col A changes) I just pulled off the net. Not sure why it isn't working, any help is appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

   If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

   Application.EnableEvents = False 'to prevent endless loop

       Dim LastRow As Long

       Dim i As Long
       LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
       For i = 3 To LastRow
           If Range("A" & i).Value = "Complete" Then
           Range("G" & i).Value = 1
           End If
    Next i
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What's not working, the whole thing, or the "middle"? Does it give you any errors? Is the sub in the correct worksheet module?

Comment: It wasn't giving any errors or anything, just not doing anything at all. I actually had the range originally set to ("A:A") (edited to show that), ("A1:A1") was just something that was in there for testing.

In any case I just restarted by computer and it worked..... still not sure what the deal was :S

Comment: Ahh yes, the ol' [turn it off and on again](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nn2FB1P_Mn8) solution.